# How to make stacked percentage columns from 1-4 scale data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large set of ordinal scale data that I would like to visualize as stacked percentage column charts. I can make what I need in excel but would like to move the process into R for a more efficient workflow. The data comes from observing behaviors and rating each observation from 1-4 on 17 different items. I need to show the percentage of each rating for each item in a stacked column.

My first issue is turning the data that I have into the percentages I need. The second issue is turning it into a ggplot visualization. Though I'm pretty certain that this can all be done in a few lines of code, I'm not really sure how to do it. When I make these charts in excel, I have to use a formula along the lines of =COUNTIF(V2:V295,1)/COUNTA(V2:V295), but for each scale level and for each indicator. Then I turn that into stacked percentage column charts, which is all point and click.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 17
     S1    S2    S3 Skills    T4    T5    T6 Thinking    A7    A8    A9 Application   R10   R11   R12
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     4     4      4     3     3     3        3     4     4     2           4     4     4     3
2     3     4     3      3     3     3     2        3     3     3     1           3     3     3     2
3     3     3     3      3     2     2     1        2     3     2     1           2     3     1     3
4     4     3     3      3     3     3     3        3     2     2     1           2     3     2     3
5     4     3     3      3     3     3     2        3     2     3     3           3     4     2     3
6     4     4     3      4     3     3     3        3     2     3     2           3     4     3     4
# ... with 2 more variables: Relationships <dbl>, Overall <dbl>
```

From this, I would like a stacked column chart that shows the percentage of each of the scale values (1-4) by column (S1, S2, S3 etc). Any guidance would be appreciated!

Oh yeah, would like to stay in tidyverse as much as possible to get this done, though if I need another package to deal with this type of data I'm game.

Comment: If you could provide your data with `dput` this would make it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to know what exactly you are looking for. But here is an attmept, maybe with some comments we can zero in on it. But from what I gather you need to gather your data into long format then group by and summarise to get counts on your scale values dependent on the items. You can then get proportions by grouping on a column and using `prop.table`.

The `melt` is turning the data from wide to long format so that grouping can be done. It also allows `ggplot` to nicely plot and group the data!

```
df <- tibble::tribble(  
~S1,  ~S2,  ~S3,  ~Skills,  ~T4,  ~T5,  ~T6,  ~Thinking,  ~A7,  ~A8,  ~A9,  ~Application,  ~R10,  ~R11,  ~R12,
4,  4,  4,  4,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  2,  4,  4,  4,  3,
3,  4,  3,  3,  3,  3,  2,  3,  3,  3,  1,  3,  3,  3,  2,
3,  3,  3,  3,  2,  2,  1,  2,  3,  2,  1,  2,  3,  1,  3,
4,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  2,  2,  1,  2,  3,  2,  3,
4,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  2,  3,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  2,  3,
4,  4,  3,  4,  3,  3,  3,  3,  2,  3,  2,  3,  4,  3,  4)

prop_table  <- df %>% 
  reshape2::melt() %>% 
  group_by(value, variable) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(prop = prop.table(n))

prop_table %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = prop, fill = as.factor(value))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack")
```